# How do I search an NSString sentence with words separated by commas for a specific word in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nspredicate

I came across a question that had an example using rangeOfString. How ever the first thing that came to mind was NSPredicate.

I have different strings that return words separated by sentences. For example I have one that returns "Male, Female".

What is the most efficient way to search either "Male" or "Female". I'd like to perform some actions if the word happens to be part of the sentence and if it doesn't.

**NSDictionary with stored words separated by commas. I use different keys to grab specific bunch of words. Below I use the "selectedGenders" key which returns "Male, Female":**

```
    if ([combinedRefinementSelection valueForKey:@"selectedGenders"]) {

        NSString *selectedGenders = [combinedRefinementSelection valueForKey:@"selectedGenders"];

        // Show string in label so customer knows how their clothes items will be filtered
        [[_thisController chosenGender] setText:selectedGenders];

    }
```

I simply want to search selectedGenders and find out if Male or Female is part of the string.

Comment: Could you post an example of your data? It sounds like CSV (comma separated values), but your full question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, rangeOfString works just fine.

```
NSString* sentence = @"Male, Female";

if ([sentence rangeOfString:@"Male"].location != NSNotFound)
{
   NSLog(@"Male is found");
}

if ([sentence rangeOfString:@"Female"].location != NSNotFound)
{
   NSLog(@"Female is found");
}
```

Comment: Worked, nice and straight forward.

Comment: Of course, if it's `@"female, female"` then the search for `@"male"` will return true.

Comment: true but searching for @"Male" won't ;)